# How to set scrolling speed in KUbuntu?

Tags: kubuntu, mouse, scrolling, mouse-scroll

I've searched how to set scrolling in KUbuntu, but couldn't find a solution. It just seems strange to me that such a basic thing isn't present on linux.

First, let me clarify why this is **not** a duplicate:

- On April 11, 2020, [this](https://pointieststick.com/2020/04/11/this-week-in-kde-libinput-scroll-speed-dolphin-remote-access-improvements-and-more/) paper was published, which said "It’s now possible to configure the scrolling speed for mice and touchpads when using Wayland (Méven Car, Plasma 5.19.0)"
- All other questions about this topic were published *after* April 11, 2020. So that means, those questions are outdated and currently there is a possible solution.

So can someone explain me how to adjust the scroll speed in KUbuntu? (KUbuntu = KDE + Ubuntu) The quotation above says this is possible and it would be important since the default linux scroll speed is *really* slow.

I know the imwheel solution, but when I tested it I encountered some silly glitches like double-scroll in Chrome. What happened in Chrome was when I scrolled, it scrolled a little and after a second it scrolled again. It could possibly be because imwheel reacts later to the scroll event from the mouse.

Answer (score 0):

It says it's possible when using wayland, are you sure you use it?
Anyway I use imwheel.

`sudo apt-get install imwheel`

Here is the script for a small GUI: http://www.nicknorton.net/?q=node/10
Don't forget to autostart `imwheel` in system settings.